# Groovy. How to ignore method call if parameter is null? Is it possible to use null safe operator for the method in my case?

Tags: groovy, junit, parameters, parameter-passing

My groovy code is bellow:

```
String start
String startParam
String end
String endParam
String rule
Period period
String exDates
PeriodList expected = new PeriodList(true)

// init variables...

    VEvent event = new ContentBuilder().vevent {
        dtstart(start, parameters: parameters() { value(startParam) })
        dtend(end, parameters: parameters() { value(endParam) })
        rrule(rule)
        exdate(exDates)
    }
```

It works correctly in general, but if some of parameters were not defined with non `null` value I get an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create component for 'exdate' reason: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.createNode(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:719)
at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.dispatchNodeCall(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:855)
at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:779)
at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.invokeMethod(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:499)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:423)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:346)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at net.fortuna.ical4j.model.VEventRecurrenceParametrizedTest$_test_closure2.doCall(VEventRecurrenceTest.groovy:79)
```

Is it possible to protect the property call (ignore one if variable is `null`)? I checked documentation, there is `null-safe-operator`. How could I use one for this case for example?

> exdate(exDates)

`exdate` should not be called if `exDates` is null.

if I try

```
exdate(this.?exDates)
```

it won't help because null safe operator will not protect method call if value is null, beside that this code `exdate(this.?exDates)` has compile error.

Comment: `if (exDates) exdate(exDates)` ?

Comment: @tim_yates yea, it seems simply, elegant and helps, move your comment to answer part please

Comment: Done :-) . Glad I could help!  Have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for it being null or empty before making the call:

```
VEvent event = new ContentBuilder().vevent {
    dtstart(start, parameters: parameters() { value(startParam) })
    dtend(end, parameters: parameters() { value(endParam) })
    rrule(rule)
    if (exDates) exdate(exDates)
}
```